# I would like to trasform a long and short strategy in a just long strategy

Tags: pine-script

How could i make this strategy just for the long, closing the long position instead of going short?

Many thanks!

```py
//Noro
//2019

//@version=3
strategy(title = "Noro's TrendTrader Strategy v1.0", shorttitle = "TT str", overlay = true, default_qty_type = strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value = 100, pyramiding = 0)

//Settings

len        = input(21, minval=1)

mult       = input(3, minval=1)

//Line

atr        = wma(atr(1), len)

highestC   = highest(len)

lowestC    = lowest(len)

hiLimit    = highestC[1] - (atr[1] * mult)

loLimit    = lowestC[1] + (atr[1] * mult)

ret = 0.0

ret := close > hiLimit and close > loLimit ? hiLimit : close < loLimit and close < hiLimit ? loLimit : nz(ret[1])

plot(ret, color= blue , title = "Trend Trader")

//Trading

if low > ret and close < open

    strategy.entry("L", strategy.long)

if high < ret and close > open

    strategy.entry("S", strategy.short)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your strategy execute a short position when the condition (`high < ret and close > open`) is met, and automatically close the long position.

To close long and not execute a short change the line 39:

```
strategy.entry("S", strategy.short)
```

to

```
strategy.close("L", when = high < ret and close > open)
```

[image]